# Pq aparece esse resultado estranho ao imprimir os valores definidos na classe ? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, classes

Galera, eu criei essa classe (classe Car), depois defini os valores para cada argumento dessa classe. Só que ao imprimir a variável com os valores já definidos, aparece isso:

```
#isso é o que aparece ao imprimir a variável car1
<Car object at 0x7fa71d52fb10>


class Car(object):
  condition = "new"
  def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
    self.model = model
    self.color = color
    self.mpg   = mpg

  def display_car(self):
    print("This is a %s %s with %s MPG." % (self.color, self.model, str(self.mpg))

  def drive_car(self):
    self.condition = "used"

car1 = Car('Monza', 'marron', 55)
print(car1)#É ESSA variável que, ao ser imprimida, imprime aquele valor estranho.
```

somente a nível de curiosidade, eu gostaria de saber o porque desse comportamento.

OBS:Lembrando que sou estudante autodidata em programação, portanto, tenham um pouco mais de paciência, ok?

Desde já agradeço a colaboração de vcs, valew galera!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos analisar passo a passo seu código:

```
class Car(object):
  condition = "new"
  def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
    self.model = model
    self.color = color
    self.mpg   = mpg
```

Você possui uma classe que modela um carro, essa classe possui os atributos: Modelo , cor e mpg (que eu não sei o que é)

```
  def display_car(self):
    print("This is a %s %s with %s MPG." % (self.color, self.model, 
str(self.mpg))

  def drive_car(self):
    self.condition = "used"
```

A sua classe também possui métodos que 'fazem' algo com os atributos.

```
car1 = Car('Monza', 'marron', 55)
print(car1)
```

Quando o objeto carro é criado, o mesmo recebe os valores 'Monza' para modelo, 'marron' para cor e '55' para mpg(que ainda não sei o que é).
Dessa forma a variável 'car1' é um **objeto**, quando você tenta imprimir um objeto você recebe como retorno a posição desse objeto na memoria do computador.

```
<Car object at 0x7fa71d52fb10>
```

Isso acontece porque um objeto é simplesmente um objeto :D Como assim ? 
Um objeto por si só não faz nada, ele apenas recebe seus valores e assim passa a existir. Para 'manipular' o objeto e 'dar vida' ao mesmo usa-se os métodos. 
Dessa forma se você quisesse imprimir os valores que foram atribuiudos a *car1* você precisa fazer essa interação por meio de um método que por sinal já existe em seu código que é o *display_car*.

```
car1.display_car #Deve imprimir os atributos de seu carro.
```

Comment: sua resposta foi SEN-SA-CIONAL, muito clara e objetiva, muito obrigado!, parabéns!!!

Comment: Valeu Eduardo , se precisar estamos ai :D